# AND query in elasticsearch with curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, lucene

Let's inject some data in Elasticsearch

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1' -d '{ "author": "John", "published_from":"2016-08-03" }'
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/external/2' -d '{ "author": "Jeanne", "published_from":"2016-08-03" }'
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/external/3' -d '{ "author": "Jean", "published_from":"2016-08-05" }'
```

I am trying to query document with published_from=2016-08-03 and author=John.
I try to do it with this curl command:

```
curl -g "localhost:9200/customer/external/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source.author&q=+author:John+published_from:2016-08-03"
```

Yet, the output displays Jeanne

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "author" : "John"
        }
      },
      {
        "_source" : {
          "author" : "Jeanne"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I try this curl command :

```
curl "localhost:9200/customer/external/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source.author&q=%2Bauthor%3AJohn+%2Bpublished_from%3A2016-08-03"
```

The output is exactly what I want.

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "author" : "John"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Why is the first command not working as expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`+` signs** in the first URL:

```
...&q=+author:John+published_from:2016-08-03
```

are interpreted (on server-side), in accordance to the [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) rules **as spaces**. The space is usually encoded as `%20`, but for historical reasons, `+` is also a valid encoding of the space character.

That means the query string that ElasticSearch gets looks like:

```
author:John published_from:2016-08-03
```

According to [query string syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators), it will find any document that contains one or more of `author:John` or `published_from:2016-08-03`.

When you properly encode the Elastic's `+` operator (in the second URL), the query received is:

```
+author:John +published_from:2016-08-03
```

Note the `+` was decoded as space , and `%2B` as `+`.

#### Simple query parameter encoding in `curl`

To avoid manual (percent-)encoding of queries, you can use the [`--data-urlencode`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) option, and provide raw `key=value` pairs.

For example:

```
curl -G 'localhost:9200/customer/external/_search?pretty&filter_path=hits.hits._source.author' --data-urlencode 'q=+author:John +published_from:2016-08-03'
```

Here `curl` will combine the query parameters from the URL with those provided with the `-d`/`--data-urlencode` options. We need `-G` to force a `GET` request, since `-d`/`--data-urlencode` defaults to a `POST` request.

Comment: I thought the option -g in curl was preventing the encoding. --data-urlencode was exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks !

Comment: The `-g` option prevents `{}[]` expansion (you don't really need it in your example), but it doesn't encode query params. You're welcome!